# Assign names to existing data frames with a For look

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following data frames. These already exist and they are identical but with different contents and row count.  I want to assign dataframe FX_nyear to Astar in each iteration.

FX_3year

FX_4year

FX_5year
...

and I want to run some complex analysis etc. I do not want to use lapply. Just a simple For loop as shown below:

`for(n in 3:n)
    {  Astar      = assign(paste("FX_",n,"year",sep="")) }`

While I can get Astar named to "FX_3year" using only paste, I am having trouble setting Astar to the actual pre-existing data frame FX_3year.

I know this is a very basic question and variants of this have been asked in the past, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Question is slightly unclear. Do you want to assign dataframe FX_nyear to Astar in each iteration?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get()

```
for(i in 3:n){
    assign("Astar",get(paste("FX_",i,"year",sep="")))
}
```

Comment: The get is what makes the difference in my case, and I picked it up yesterday. Thank you a lot.